# HL7 server sends no response to two simple apps created in .NET and PHP

Tags: php, .net, hl7

I tried using a client which is - HL7 Soup - which I downloaded on the net, it is sending and receiving successfully.  But when I tried using my 2 custom applications, which were created in .NET and PHP, they successfully connect to the HL7 server, and presumably send, but both do not get any response. What could be the problem with the messages I'm sending or with the code I created?

Please refer to the codes which are in the links below.

http://pastebin.com/b2J3z3J9
http://pastebin.com/0dTHVKVs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you implement the MLLP protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Usually MLLP (a transport protocol, there are others) is used to signal the recipient where the message starts and where it ends.

Typically you send:

```
<start of block><data><end of block><carriage return>
```

where

```
<start of block> is usually 0x0b
<end of block> is usually 0x1c
<carriage return> is always 0x0d
```

The answer (ACK/NAK) is also wrapped like this.
So your code lacks wrapping the .

Just search for mllp+hl7 on the web.